# How do I access the id of the current object while in "show"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails so bear with me on this.
I've added a link to the `"show"` page that's supposed to take the `id` of the current page you're on, and add it, along with some other data to an entry in another model.
How do I access this `id` in the controller?

Let's say I'm on `/products/1`
How do I get `"1"`? All attempts to get the current link produce links without the parameter on the end.

Thanks for your time.

Code:
This is what my route to the action is:

```
get 'added' => 'products#add_to_cart'
```

The link I'm using in show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Add to cart", {:controller => "products", :action => "add_to_cart", :product => @product.id}%>
```

and the action itself

```
  def add_to_cart
    @cart = Cart.new
    @cart.username = current_user.id
    @cart.product_name = params[:id]
    @cart.price = 100
    @cart.amount = 1
    @cart.save
    @products = Product.all
    render "index"
  end
```

Comment: You just use `params[:id]`.

Comment: You cannot get the `id` because you are in `add_to_cart` not in `show`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of show is like this:

`get '/products/:id', to: 'products#show'`

So you can simply get it using:

```
params[:id]
```

UPDATE:

In the above question updates, instead of using:
`params[:id]`
it should use:
`params[:product]`

Comment: I have already tried this, but it does not appear to work.
This is how I am trying to use it:     
 @cart.product_name = params[:id]

Comment: Could you post your code related you your issue so we can determine it. Your `routes` and `controller`.

Comment: This is what my route to the action is: `get 'added' => 'products#add_to_cart'`

and the action itself 
 `def add_to_cart
    @cart = Cart.new
    @cart.username = current_user.id
    @cart.product_name = params[:id]
    @cart.price = 100
    @cart.amount = 1
    @cart.save
    @products = Product.all
    render "index"
  end`

Comment: Don't post your code in the comment, update your question above with the following code.

Comment: In your post above, you want to get the value of `id` under `products`. But you can't get the `id` using `params[:id]` because you are not accessing it. You are accessing `add_to_card` not in `show`.

Comment: Are you using a `link` to trigger the `add_to_cart` method? Please post it.

Comment: I have added the link to the question.
If possible, I would like to stay on show after add_to_cart.

Comment: Where `@product.id` came from `(:product => @product.id)`? Could you add some details? Is it your link is within the loop? Example: `<% @products.each do |product| %> <%= link_to ... %> <% end %>`?

Comment: That was a remnant from some earlier attempts. It turns out simply using params[:product] instead of params[:id] got me the id number I needed.
Thank you very much for all your help.